# How to set `TIme.current`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'Lima'
```

When I write `"Time.current"` on rails console, it shows this:

```
Fri, 18 Mar 2016 10:22:04 PET -05:00
```

I want to create an `Order` with `Time.current` for `order_date`. But instead of inserting `"2016-03-18 10:22:04"`, it shows:

```
"order_date", "2016-03-18 15:22:10.227519"
```

What should I do to fix that?

Comment: Rails stores times in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

Comment: how can i set that? :(

Comment: Why would you need to change that? When you’ll read it back, assuming `config.time_zone = 'Lima'` remains in config, you’ll get `Fri, 18 Mar 2016 10:22:04 PET -05:00`.

Comment: But in my column "order_date" and  "created_at" no insert "10:22:04" , it insert this : "15:22:04" .
Apparently this advance 5 hours :/

Comment: @Giancarlos no, 10:22:04 PET is 15:22:04 CET.

Answer (score 0):

Rails stores times in in database in UTC. When you read from database, rails formats them back to your local time zone which is defined in config/application.rb. 
Probably never you need to store times in local timezone in database.